# Why won't Rails 4 uninstall?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After uninstalling Rails 4(RC1) I still get Rails 4 apps generated with `rails new`.

```
➲ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0.rc1
➲ which rails
/Users/brandon/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/rails
➲ gem uninstall rails

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. rails-3.2.13
 2. rails-3.2.3
 3. All versions
>
```

What's the cleanest way to fix this?

Comment: Any update on this? Have you gotten things resolved?

Comment: yes, but I got sidetracked by another problem... I should have something posted soon...

Comment: @zeantsoi: fuller answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TL;DR:

### The simplest and safest solution to the immediate problem is

```
gem uninstall railties
```

---

## Slightly Longer & More Complete Approach

If you want to uninstall everything that `gem install rails` installed, you can get a list of commands to run with this:

```
gem dependency rails --pipe | ruby -ne 'puts $_.gsub(/\([0-9\. <>=~,]*\)/,"")' | ruby -ne 'puts "gem uninstall #{$_}"'
```

Copy those and run them one-by-one, and for each one you'll be told what else depends on it, and asked if you want to go ahead with uninstallation.  If you see anything in the list that is not part of rails (say you've installed something else that needs that version of `active_record`) then leave it, otherwise go ahead and uninstall.

---

## The longer explanation

The version displayed is taken from the version of the `railties` gem, which is not uninstalled by uninstalling the `rails` gem.

If you open the `rails` executable with

```
vim `which rails`
```

(or the equivalent with the editor of your choice) you'll see the code at the bottom that decides which version of rails to use based on the version of `railties`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby_noexec_wrapper
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'railties', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

The simplest solution, therefore, is just to `gem install railsties`.  There is no solution built-into RubyGems (that I can find) that will detect which other gems were installed with rails ***and are no longer used by anything else*** and uninstall them.  RubyGems does not have the idea of an exclusive dependency, so even though nothing else besides `rails` uses `railties`, you're still stuck having to know that it (and several other things) are left over and must be manually uninstalled.  This is not ideal, but it's what we've got right now, and it's not that bad, especially if you use the solution above to find and remove all the rails dependencies.

Answer (score 10):

It is quite easy.

```
gem uninstall rails -v=4.0.0.rc1
gem uninstall railties
gem install rails -v 3.2.13
gem update --system
rails -v
```

By using commands above I was able to install older version of rails as needed :)

Comment: The key here is uninstalling railties, which I already pointed out, as did others. If you have a way of uninstalling everything that was installed with rails in one command, that would be useful. Something like `gem uninstall rails --with-dependencies -v=4.0.0.rc1`.  But there's no new info in this answer.

Comment: Worked for me on moving from rails 4.0 to 3.2

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying your installed version:

```
gem uninstall rails -v=4.0.0.rc1
```

EDIT:

If you've already uninstalled (which you have), the following should work:

```
gem update --system
rails _3.2.2_ new app_name # or whatever version you're on
```

Answer (score 2):

Rails does not come as an all-in-one package. You have a base Rails gem, plus it's many dependencies:

- Action Mailer
- Action Pack
- Active Record
- Active Resource
- Active Support
- Bundler
- Railties  <---- (contains generators)
- Sprockets adapter for Rails

To get rid of your Rails 4 installation as a whole, you must remove all of these gems.

The easiest way to do this is to **delete your entire gem folder**, then reinstall whatever you need.

Comment: of course it's a large number of gems, but somehow I thoughtlessly assumed the uninstallation would be clever enough to handle this use case, but obviously not.  Since the dependencies are *just other gems* to rubygems, rather than somehow specifically a part of Rails, it treats them the same way it would treat any other dependency....

Comment: Actually, `sudo gem cleanup` will help you to deleting every dependency. However, it's not working for me, lots dependencies wrong even if after I re-install the older version

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, this worked as a simple fix for me:

Please note that in order to shift back to 3.2.13 (or whatever version you'd like to go back to), you must remove Railties as well as Rails.

Just do:

`gem uninstall rails`

Then, select the version of Rails 4 you have and delete it.

Then, do:

`gem uninstall railties`

And do the same thing.

When I uninstalled the Rails 4 version of railties, it told me that dependencies for a couple gems (coffee-rails and sass-rails) wouldn't be met. So I just did the same thing with both of them as I did above (such as, `gem uninstall sass-rails`), and deleted their Rails 4 versions as well. For example, for sass-rails, I had a version installed called sass-rails-4.0.0.rc1, so I uninstalled that version).

And that's it; the terminal will list 3.2.13 as your current Rails version, and new apps will be generated from this version as well.

Comment: yes, I've done that, but it doesn't get the whole tree of dependencies, and it's a manual process.  It's also not a general solution.  It works for rails as long as you know that railties is a key item you need to uninstall, but it doesn't work for anything else.

Comment: This process worked for myself and several others that I know of, but I guess not for you. I'll let you know if I hear of a different solution. Are your newly generated apps still in Rails 4, and/or have you made any progress on your problem?